# Unique constraint over two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint

I have two tables:
`Country` : has ID, Name
`State`   : has ID, Name, CountryID

I defined `Country.Name` as unique.

I also want to define `State.Name` as unique *per country* - i.e. I can't just define it as unique because two countries may have the same state. But for one country, every state is unique.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define `UNIQUE` for both columns `Name` and `CountryID`  as below:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uix ON State( Name, CountryID)
```